# New gas furnace...... installer used old non polarized plug from previous furnace

Tags: electrical, furnace, natural-gas

Have a new 60kbtu furnace. Installer used power cord from old dinosaur (non polarized). This was unknown by me until last week, 6 months after install. We lose power up here a lot, and after the last one (3 days) the furnace wouldn’t come on, but light was blinking slow and steady. Code 11 states a polarity issue. Sure enough, the plug looks to be older than me. No polarity and can see both wires at the prongs. Installer is....... not interested in coming back. Got furnace working after several shut-offs but am certain this will be an ongoing issue. Have tester, and polarity is correct at outlet. Can I change out the power cord on the furnace or do I have to call another licensed HVAC person to do so? And if I can do it, what type cord am I looking for? Can someone point this “getting too old for this stuff” lady in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: Local regulations will matter if you can legally do it yourself.  Does sound like someone with the knowledge should be able to do it themselves, it is not rocket science.  Does sound nice it is on a plug, just need to fire up generator to have heat(some are hardwired to panel).

Comment: report the installer's work to the local HVAC licensing office

Comment: Ask for warranty repair, you should still have it. Just keep calling and complaining the unit is out.

Comment: You need an electrician to put a dedicated outlet and a means of disconnect (a light switch, which makes it easy to power cycle the unit; I suspect the cord isn't the only problem: you'll be using that switch often to get the unit to restart). **NEC says *no* on corded furnaces.**

Comment: Although I agree with the statement from the NEC stating no cords I believe there needs to be clarified as some mfg’s want the control power on a cord. A home owner can ALWAYS replace the cord cap. 
The cord cap is the proper name for the “plug” you can find them for 2$ to 20$ depending on the quality you will probably need a 15 amp model.

Comment: Thanks all! Have another electrician coming out on Saturday to look. Bought a 3 wire, 14 AWG, 15 A, appliance cord. Going to see what he says. Waiting for last week’s generac estimate to arrive as well. Was told those are on back order until who knows when. One day...... one day.